# Why absolutely positioned element in a table cell is wrapping?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

Consider the following: [(Live Demo)](http://jsbin.com/ofesuv/1/edit)

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>      
      <td class="col1">
        <button class="btn btn-small">Do Something</button> 
      </td>
      <td class="col2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1"></td>
      <td class="col2">
        <span style="position: relative">
          Text 
          <button class="btn btn-small" 
                  style="position: absolute; 
                         top: 0; 
                         left: 210px">
            Do Something
          </button>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
tr {
  height: 100px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col1 {
  width: 150px;
}
.col2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Why the absolutely positioned button is wrapping?

I could solve it by:

```css
button {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but I'm really interested to know why this wrapping is happening, and whether there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: Any reason for `position:absolute;`? As in the above scenario, if I replace absolute positioning with `position:relative` keeping `left: 176px;` and `top:0;` the purpose is served.

Comment: @Nathan: Yes. I don't want the button to affect other cell elements positioning (in this case the `Text`). If you try to change `.col2` width to `50px`, for example, you'll see that with `position: relative` the `Text` is not vertically centered anymore: http://jsbin.com/ujilig/1/edit

Comment: @NathanLee even with position relative, it will wrap again if you make it longer, something like "Do Somethiiiiiiiiiiiiiiinnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng". I think since no width is assigned to the button, as well as no `right` alongside `left`, the button will try to take the smallest size. (by wrapping)

Answer (score 0):

It is wrapping to avoid overflowing the parent container in this case. It is still overflowing it because you have too long of a single word, but the behavior is to try to not overflow it. If you change your demo to have more text in your other button you would see it wraps as well once it exceeds the table cell width.

Use the `white-space: nowrap` if you want to avoid this.